# MVC3 Entity Framework Code First Updating Subset Related List of Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, list, code-first

I have a table of data with a list of key value pairs in it.

```
Key            Value
--------------------
ElementName    PrimaryEmail 
Email          someemail@gmail.ca   
Value          Content/Images/logo-here.jpg
```

I am able to generate new items on my client webpage. When, I create a new row on the client and save it to the server by executing the following code the item saves to the database as expected.

```
public ViewResult Add(CardElement cardElement) 
{      
   db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
   db.SaveChange();
   return Json(obj);
}
```

Now, when I want to delete my objects by sending another ajax request I get a failure.

```
public void Delete(CardElement[] cardElements)
{
    foreach (var cardElement in cardElements)
    {
        db.Entry(cardElement).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This results in the following error.

***Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.***

I have tried other ways of deleting including find by id remove and attach and delete but obviously I am approaching in the right fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is causing your issue, but I tend to structure my deletes as follows:

```
public void Delete(CardElement[] cardElements)
{
    foreach (var cardElement in cardElements)
    {
        var element = db.Table.Where(x => x.ID == cardElement.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if(element != null)
           db.DeleteObject(element);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

although I tend to do database first development, which may change things slightly.

EDIT: the error you are receiving states that no rows were updated. When you pass an object to a view, then pass it back to the controller, this tends to break the link between the object and the data store. That is why I prefer to look up the object first based on its ID, so that I have an object that is still linked to the data store.